# What format are ATOC master stations file "Eastings" and "Northings" in?

Tags: coordinates, geography

## The Problem

I have downloaded the Master Stations Names File from the UK's Rail Delivery group.
I'm trying to map the dataset and would like to extract the locations. I tried using pyproj in my Python script, but the results are wrong.
The "Eastings" and "Northings" they provide don't seem to fit the National Grid. For example:

York station is given as "14596 64517". If these were epsg:27700, they would translate to -7.420284219986337 50.35401717940486, which is somewhere off the coast of Cornwall.

The documentation for the file says the following:

> "Easting in units of 100m. Stations too far south
>   (Channel Islands) or too far north (Orkneys) or too far
>   west (west of Carrick on Shannon) have both their
>   Easting and Northing set to 00000. The most westerly
>   station in range, Carrick on Shannon, has value
>   10000. The most easterly station, Amsterdam, has
>   value 18690."

and

> "Northing in units of 100m. Stations too far south
>   (Channel Islands) or too far north (Orkneys) or too far
>   west (west of Carrick on Shannon) have both their
>   Easting and Northing set to 00000.
>   The most
>   southerly station in range, Lizard (Bus), has value
>   60126. The most northerly station in range, Scrabster,
>   has value 69703."

but that still doesn't tell me the actual format they are in.
Google didn't help - I'm not even sure what to look for.

## Question

What format are these coordinates in and how can I transform them into epsg:4326?

Answer (score 0):

One would think that such a seemingly custom format would be better documented but there you go.
After much experimenting and playing with the coordinates given, I came up with the formula:

```py
realEastings = (eastingsInData - 10000) * 100
realNorthings = (northingsInData - 60000) * 100
```

Why anyone would use this is beyond me, but hopefully this post can be useful for somebody else.