# How to transform EPSG:6249 coordinates to "standard" lat/lon coordinates?

Tags: coordinates, projection, qgis, epsg

I have a set of coordinate points in a format refer to as "MAGNA-SIRGAS / Cali urban grid" or "EPSG:6249". Each point coordinates are labeled as North and East. I would like to transform the coordinates to WGS84 (EPSG:4326) coordinates. I have tried several tools online but they fail to transform the values.

Example : North = 861597.4129 , East = 1063313.808

Comment: What do you mean with "standard lat/lon" coordinates? There is no standard one. Maybe you want to convert to WGS84 (which has also the code EPSG:4326). This is used by GPS, so now many countries uses such data as reference for lat/long

Answer (score 0):

In QGIS if your points in EPSG:6249 are correctly located ..
you can check this  adding a satellite image as backgroup (using  google maps or BingQ )

then just save(in the format you prefer eg: shape file)  the layer with SR =  WGS84 (EPSG:4326)

the new layer is a EPSG:4326 so your lat, lng are now in the format you are looking for

And as correctly mentioned  by @Giacomo Catenazzi in comment there is not  a standard coordinates referece system  (SR) but all the SR are standardized  by EPSG. In recent time the use of GPS and tools as Google Maps are produced amost common  or most used  SR (EPSG:4326)

Comment: Seems a Bugs for your version of QGIS ..  try using an intermediate SR

Comment: The data comes from an official study so I quite sure it is correct. However, when I add the map it does not show. Maybe there is an operation missing like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54555623/what-format-are-atoc-master-stations-file-eastings-and-northings-in?rq=1

Comment: have you tried  to show the data over a satellite maps  (eg:google maps) ? the data are corretcly located? ..  if YES then try save the layer with a different SR .. and reload  the new saved  datas amd try to save as WGS 84 (EPSG:4326 )